# Distributed computing using message queue VS Map/Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, amqp, hdfs

Context:

We are considering an AMQP-compliant solution as a way to compute a constant live stream of data that amounts to 90 gb daily. What we'd like to achieve is live stats, more or less, based on all or some combination of the metrics we're observing. The considered strategy is to send data on the queue and have worker process deltas of the data, sending the data back on the queue as an aggregation of the original data.

Observation:

To me, this looks like a job for something like Hadoop, but concerns (and shields) were raised, mainly about speed. I didn't have the time to benchmark both, we're expecting to pump a good amount of data through the queue (anywhere in the neighborhood of 10~100 mb/s) though. I still think it looks like a job for a distributed computing system, and I also feel the queue solution will scale poorer than a distributed computing solution.

Question:

Put simply, am I right? I've read a bit on Hadoop + HDFS, I was thinking about using another FS, like Lustre or something, to circumvent the NodeName SPOF, and use some kind of solution to have some kind of tolerance to failure of nodes of any kind on the whole cluster.

Comment: It looks like your question is: Should I use existing map-reduce framework or write my own one. And the answer is: Depends on your goal. If you need something which just works (even with some learning involved) use existing one. If you want to create something new - write your own one.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mind making one or using one, I really am looking for the best way to chomp away in real time at several dozens GB of data daily to pump live stats out of the data. We're currently looking at a message queue to pull it off, but I was thinking that distributed computation using Map/Reduce would maybe me more fitted to do that.

Comment: Well, then Hadoop is the right tool for you. Of course, you will need to copy your data into HDFS (but 90gb per day is not much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its really hard to write your own "distributed environment" solution when you need fail-tolarence, good balancing, etc.If you need near-realtime map/reduce you should checkout [storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) which is what twitter uses for their huge data needs. Its less complicated then hadoop, and better on consuming queue type input (In my opinion).

Also if you decide to analyze your data on hadoop don't worry too much on SPOF of name node, there are [some ways](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/high-availability-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system-hdfs/) to avoid it.

Comment: Real interesting read/talk! For the Hadoop hdfs spof, I was thinking of using a distributed filesystem (some are apparently hadoop-compatible). Is that feasible?

Comment: hadoop is mostly for batch operations, so your "real-time" requirement would not be meet. I use hadoop for complex operations on relatively big data (~500gb) on weekly/daily/hourly basis. For near real-time operations I prefer storm + kafka.